# ¿Cómo consultar excel almacenado en Sharepoint con php?

Tags: php, sharepoint

Tengo en un excel almacenado en Sharepoint con información que es modificada por varias personas que están en lugares distintos, y necesito verificar unos valores que están en el excel cada 5 Minutos durante las 24 horas del día por lo que se hace bien difícil hacerlo manual y debido a esto estoy intentando desarrollar algo que verifique esos valores y a su vez envié correos de alertas en caso de variar, pero el problema esta en que no se como consultar esos valores del excel que esta almacenado en el Sharepoint.

Muchas Gracias de antemano

Comment: Dispone Sharepoint de alguna API para este tipo de acceso?, de lo contrario, tendrías que ver la forma de obtener el archivo desde PHP para analizarlo, que tampoco me parece que sea lo más óptimo. Tal vez sería más viable lograrlo por medio de macros, pero desconozco la plataforma y no puedo hacer una sugerencia más a fondo.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta según he investigado existe SharePointAPI y estoy trabajando con ella pero no he logrado mucho, Muchas Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Intenta haciendo y exponiendo un servicio web que obtenga la informacion necesaria del excel y lo consumes desde php